# My code to bind data works on windows but not on mac

Tags: r

I'm trying to join my 6 .csv files by via their rows.

The top code works on my windows computer. However, I used the same code on my mac with the changed file path (bottom code) but the output .csv file is completely empty. Does anyone know what went wrong here?

```
joined.data<- do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(
                      path ="C:/User/R work/filtered data"), 
                      read.csv, header=T, sep=","))

joined.data<- do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(
                      path = "/Users/Documents/Filtered data"), 
                      read.csv, header=T, sep=","))
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the file paths correct? What does `list.files()` return in each of those cases. I would guess the mac version doesn't return any files.

Comment: The path for my Mac Documents folder is: /Users/{my_user_name}/Documents